# Are initial submanifolds cofibrations?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

In Natural Operations in Differential Geometry by Kolar, Michor, & Slovak, they define an initial submanifold as follows:
[image]
They can be shown to satisfy the following universal property:
[image]

I am aware that the inclusion of an embedded submanifold is a cofibration, and I am wondering if the same holds for the more general class of initial submanifolds?